# Should I initialize mock objects in setup or in the test case?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

In unit testing with help of mock/fake objects, I wonder whether it's more preferable to initialize the mocks in SetUp or in the test method itself, if my test class contains methods that test the same class (and thus, fake object needed should be the same for all test case). Something like this:

```
class FooTests
{
    Mock<IBar> mockBar;
    Foo fooUnderTest;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        mockBar = new Mock<IBar>();
        fooUnderTest = new fooUnderTest(mockBar.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        //setup mock methods
        mockBar.SetUp( ... )

        //test
        fooUnderTest.TestSomething()

        //assert something here

    }
}
```

It seems that this will prevent us from duplicating code to mockBar and fooUnderTest in each test case, but the downside is that I have to declare class variables mockBar and fooUnderTest (or is this really a downside?), and it will be problematic if I want to have some special setup (for example, if in some testcase I want to overriede some of the virtual methods of Foo). Any suggestion what is the best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If there is some common setup **shared by all tests in a suite/fixture** (including setting up some expectations on mock collaborators), **MOVE to a Setup method**. (Ditto for incidental details that are not relevant to the reader within the test)
- If one test case wants to **extend** common setup, add the specific **setup inline** within test-case itself
- If one test case **wants a different setup** (inspite of significant overlap), **MOVE to different test suite** and figure out some other mechanism to share setup (e.g. via composition, utility methods, Object Mothers, etc.)

Comment: very nice and sensible guideline, thank you. Any specific suggestions for my example?

Comment: @LouisRhys - can you elaborate on what you mean by 'want to override some of the virtual methods of Foo'. Do you mean you want a different subclass of Foo for testing? If yes, that is a different setup and bullet#3 applies.